# My LoadImage isn't Working - I need to know why

Tags: c++, function, bitmap

Look At this code and please tell me why when I compile it I see a blank white screen:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static char g_szClassName[] = "TEST";
static HINSTANCE g_hInst = NULL;

int savenumber = 1;
char savestring[] = "abc";

HWND hwnd;
HDC hdcWindow;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
RECT rc;
//HBITMAP mario1,mario2,mario3,mario4,mario5,mario6,
//        block1,block2,block3,scene1,scene1mask;
HBITMAP scene1;
BITMAP bm;

LRESULT CALLBACK
WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
         HBITMAP g_hbitmap = NULL;

switch(nMsg)
{
  case WM_CREATE:   
       g_hbitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                                   "C:\\Users\\Onwer\\Desktop\\Cpp code Initiate\\Jacob                          GRAPIC#3 cpp renewal!\\G3-Images\\scene.bmp",
                                   IMAGE_BITMAP,
                                   640,
                                   320,
                                   LR_LOADFROMFILE);

       /*
       mario1 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO1BMP");
       mario2 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO2BMP");
       mario3 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO3BMP");
       mario4 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO4BMP");
       mario5 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO5BMP");
       mario6 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "MARIO6BMP");
       block1 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "BLOCK1BMP");
       block2 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "BLCOK2BMP");
       block3 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "BLOCK3BMP");
       scene1 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "SCENE1BMP");
       scene1mask = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "SCENE1MASKBMP");
       */
       scene1 = LoadBitmap(g_hInst, "SCENE1BMP");

  break;
  case WM_TIMER:
  break;
  case WM_PAINT:
       hdcWindow = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
       GetClientRect (hwnd, &rc);

       drawScene (hdcWindow);

       //DrawText(hdcWindow,"This Is a Test!", -1, &rc,
       //DT_SINGLELINE | DT_TOP | DT_TOP );

       EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);           
  break;
  case WM_COMMAND:
  break;
  case WM_CLOSE:
     DestroyWindow(hwnd);
  break;
  case WM_DESTROY:

       /*
       DeleteObject(mario1);
       DeleteObject(mario2);
       DeleteObject(mario3);
       DeleteObject(mario4);
       DeleteObject(mario5);
       DeleteObject(mario6);
       DeleteObject(block1);
       DeleteObject(block2);
       DeleteObject(block3);
       */

       PostQuitMessage(0);
  break;
  default:
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, nMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
ofstream SaveFile ("save.txt");
SaveFile << savenumber << '\n' << savestring;

WNDCLASSEX WndClass;
HWND hwndMain;
MSG Msg;
g_hInst = hInstance;

WndClass.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
WndClass.style         = 0;
WndClass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
WndClass.cbClsExtra    = 0;
WndClass.cbWndExtra    = 0;
WndClass.hInstance     = g_hInst;
WndClass.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
WndClass.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
WndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE);
WndClass.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
WndClass.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
WndClass.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);


if(!RegisterClassEx(&WndClass))
{
  MessageBox(0, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!",
     MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
  return 0;
}

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
  WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
  g_szClassName,
  "TEST",
  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
  //CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 677, 358,
  CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 800, 500,
  NULL, NULL, g_hInst, NULL);


if(hwnd == NULL)
{
  MessageBox(0, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!",
     MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
  return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hwnd);

while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
  TranslateMessage(&Msg);
  DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
return Msg.wParam;
}
```

I need to know why LoadImage doesn't display the picture designated. Is it not even supposed to? And if its not supposed t: tell me what function that goes with loadImage I should use, that is part of Windows.h in C++. I am using the Dev-C++ compiler.

Comment: The code in `drawScene` is commented out. If that's the way you're current implementation is then nothing ever gets drawn to the device.

Comment: ... yeah I know thats crud from earlier that I will remove ... BUT IM specifically talking about LoadImage inside WM_CREATE. ACTUALLY NO I commented out that void because the stuff inside didn't work - so if you could tell me how to get it to work that would be nice but I don't expect you to.

Comment: anybody who sees what captain obvlious said should know that I just removed the section he was mentioning, as it was not meant to be here. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `LoadImage` does it loads an image, nothing else. If you want your application to draw an image in a window you have to do it yourself.

The contents of `drawScene()` were commented out (since removed in an edit) and your `WM_PAINT` handler doesn't perform any drawing operations. *If* your bitmap was successfully loaded you will need to do something like below when you handle the `WM_PAINT` message.

```
hdcMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);

HGDIOBJ oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMemory, g_hbitmap);
BitBlt(hdcWindow, 0, 0, 640, 320, hdcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(hdcMemory, oldBitmap);

DeleteDC(hdcMemory);
```

Comment: thats great and all and I know that it should work, I've loaded an image a different way before and then used that(in a different program) and it worked great but In this program I get a linker error corresponding to "SelectObject@8" , "BitBlt@32" , and "DeleteDC@4".

Comment: I really want this program to work D: but no matter what I do when I use that stuff I get Linker errors.

Comment: You need to link the gdi32.lib library. Check your project settings to make sure it's in the linker config.

Comment: Thank you! but to make it even moorreee easy on me.... could you tell me how to do that? if I had money (just a kid) I'd owe you like $100 right now.

Comment: **OMFG IFIGURED OUT HOW TO LINK IT, THE IMAGE WORKS OMGOMG THANK YOU SO MUCH EVEN THOUGH I BET IF I SEARCHED HARDER I WOULD'VE FOUND THE ANSWER WITHOUT YOU BUT WHATEVA U R AN ANGEL**

Comment: You should select the bitmap back out of the memory DC before you delete it.

Comment: heyhey thanks for the advice but ive edited the program and fixed the errors so now everything is good.